# QuickSort implementation in C seems to skip some runs randomly

Tags: c, recursion, random, quicksort

i was in the process on implementing a QuickSort in C as an exercise. I think I'm in a pretty good spot by I'm puzzle by why my code seems to sometimes not call the first call of QuickSort.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>

#include "quicksort.h"
#include "utils.h"

//----------------------------------------

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    unsigned int SIZE;
    int* numbers;
    
    if (argc > 1) {
        SIZE = argc-1;
        numbers = (int*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) * SIZE);
        if (numbers == NULL) { exit(1); }
        
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            numbers[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
        }
    } else {
        SIZE = 100;
        numbers = (int*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) * SIZE);
        if (numbers == NULL) { exit(1); }
        
        srandom(time(NULL));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (random() % 60000) - 30000;    // Random numbers between (-30000, 30000)
        }
    }
    printf("Array filled!\n");

    quicksort(numbers, 0, SIZE-1);
    printf("%s\n", isSorted(numbers, SIZE) ? "Sorted!" : "Not sorted!");

    free(numbers);
    printf("Memory released\n");

    exit(0);
}
```

**quicksort.c**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "quicksort.h"
#include "utils.h"

//----------------------------------------

unsigned int partition(int* const array, const unsigned int low, const unsigned int high) {
    const int pivot = array[(unsigned int)((low + high)/2)];
    unsigned int i = low;
    unsigned int j = high;
    
    while (1) {
        while (array[i] < pivot) { i += 1; }
        while (pivot < array[j]) { j += -1; }
        if (i == j) { return i; }
        swap(array+i, array+j);
    }
}

void quicksort(int* const array, const unsigned int low, const unsigned int high) {
    unsigned int pivot = partition(array, low, high);
    printf(".");

    // We only want to recurse if there at least two elements to order.
    //  Otherwise we simply don't recurse on the subarray because one element is in order with itself.
    if (low+1 < pivot) { quicksort(array, low, pivot-1); }
    if (pivot+1 < high) { quicksort(array, pivot+1, high); }
}
```

**utils.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "utils.h"

//----------------------------------------

void print_array(int* const array, const unsigned int size) {
    printf("%d", array[0]);
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        printf(" %d", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    const int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

unsigned short isSorted(int* const array, const unsigned int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array [i+1]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    return 1;
}
```

The issue is that sometimes the first call to quicksort() is ran and I can see the dots of each call on my terminal. Sometimes it gets stuck and I can't see even one single dot.

I'm really puzzled because it's such a random error I don't even know how to start debugging it.

This is one particular instance that always get stuck.

```
./main -22167 -8962 -12961 -8232 -1118 -22237 -7872 -8654 15744 -28388 -12088 402 17865 3515 -10380 -1672 -6731 24435 14161 14906 -21791 -9593 -2111 -1323 6065 1955 -23011 17216 29229 -8988 21034 -22938 -11598 14425 -24818 -6364 -1460 -2689 14983 -15716 -24725 9247 -8962 23141 -17238 -12989 27821 -17616 -18554 11982 27290 26008 -27611 -28468 -5315 -15194 -20161 -21974 -27977 -20932 -24610 -591 22483 -29856 20186 27665 -6219 25078 -28672 15116 -20638 -23396 -5637 -23247 6097 -16523 -6236 3918 -4139 5210 22252 29504 -22430 994 7388 -21393 15800 17227 -13367 -5825 2647 28375 -64 -28518 28520 26474 5500 28653 21552 6828
```

Comment: Please simplify your [mre] by skipping the non-trivial input and working with hard-coded sample data which demonstrate the behaviour you observe (even if only for some executions).

Comment: "some utility functions such as swap, print_array and isSorted on which i have no doubt they work". You do not doubt, we might. Please include them into your MRE.

Comment: Please comment out `srandom(time(NULL));` while debugging, or you have a moving target. If the error does not occur, have it output the seed value, so you know which seed it is failing on, and then use that seed while debugging.

Comment: For SIZE == 100 one such seed is 1609864435.

Comment: Then hard code that seed while debugging so the code performs exactly the same on each run.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that. I have a feeling that my code gets stuck when I have duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0):

There was quite a few errors in the partition scheme and in the quicksort.

Correct version:
**quicksort.c**

```
unsigned int partition(int* const array, const unsigned int low, const unsigned int high) {
    const int pivot = array[(unsigned int)((low + high)/2)];
    long i = (long)low - 1;
    long j = (long)high + 1;
    
    while (1) {
        do { i += 1; } while (array[i] < pivot);
        do { j += -1; } while (pivot < array[j]);
        if (i >= j) { return j; }
        swap(array+i, array+j);
    }
}

void quicksort(int* const array, const unsigned int low, const unsigned int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        unsigned int pivot = partition(array, low, high);

        quicksort(array, low, pivot);
        quicksort(array, pivot+1, high);
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to introduce another type `unsigned i = low - 1;` is fine, even if `low == 0`.

Comment: How so? I had problems with underflow earlier and casting to long before subtracting fixed it.

Comment: I am not familiar with your earlier "problems with underflow".  I see no reason for the use of `long` here.  The portion of code  and type change from OP's `unsigned int i = low; ...   while (array[i] < pivot) { i += 1; } ...` looks unnecessary.